# python 3.2.3 Tkinter scale widget hangs when nested in Frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm relatively inexperienced with Tk, but I've done a few simple projects before and this has me stumped:

I have a scale widget that represents a time-slider.  A threading.Timer goes off at intervals to move the scale widget along.  On button-down, the thread is disabled; on button-up the thread is re-enabled.  So the user can click-drag the time-slider to reposition the application's "time."  Disabling the thread during the UI operation has so far prevented crashes I was having that I assumed was related to thread safety (seemingly non-deterministic crashes, occurred about the time the thread would be trying to update the slider).

The only other "active" UI elements are a series of buttons, which are configured using the command=fnc parameter.  The scale is the only place I'm using a bind().  The application is a full-screen app, so I'm using self.root.overridedirect(1) and geometry() at the root level to remove menues and borders, and to make it full-screen.

I have changed the code, so the scale widget is now inside a Frame instead of at absolute root level:

```
self.scale_timescrub = tkinter.Scale(self.root.master, from_=0, to=60, width=height_one, orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL, showvalue=0)
self.scale_timescrub.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=tkinter.N+tkinter.S+tkinter.E+tkinter.W)
self.scale_timescrub.bind('<Button-1>', self.press_scrub)
self.scale_timescrub.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.release_scrub)
```

Now, the application hangs whenever I try any UI operations with the scale widget.  Pressing anywhere on the slider pegs the CPU and the app never comes back.  I know it's related to the parenting because when I hack the application to put the scale back at root level, it works again.  The widget never seems to enter it's bound functions, like press_scrub, when it's parented to the frame.

Can anyone advise me what I'm doing wrong here?

Running python 3.2.3 64b on Windows 7.

Comment: Is the rest of the code available somewhere?  It would definitely help to have minimum workable example which we can play around with that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with my use of the "master" keyword as the name of my full-window Frame object.  When I bulk rename self.root.master to self.root.full_frame then everything works as expected.  Thanks to Bryan for pointing out threading dangers, which I will use to reevaluate other aspects of my application.  Thanks to mgilson for showing an interest in a reproducable.  I hadn't paired down a reproducable before posting because I thought I had so many strange configurations being set that any one of them might be involved.  Anyway, thanks to all.  Note to self: don't call anything "master."

Answer (score 0):

You wrote: "A threading.Timer goes off at intervals to move the scale widget along". In handling this timer event, are you calling widget methods from another thread? If so, that is definitely the problem. You simply cannot change the UI from another thread.

You shouldn't ever need a Timer object -- are you aware you can schedule something to run at a regular interval using `after`?

Another thing to consider, but which can't be determined by looking at your code snippet, is whether you're using `pack` in the same container widget. Combining `pack` and `grid` in the same master will cause the behavior you see. Usually you'll see that behavior at startup in such a case, but not always.

Comment: I am not using pack() and grid() in the same application.  As I tried to indicate, on button-press, I kill the Thread.timer() and on button-up and re-activate Thread.timer().  Had no problems with the correctness of this in the past, even if after() may be better programming style.  I will look into after(), but the evidence points to the Frame parent as having something to do with it.

Comment: @Mayur Patel: Even though you kill the timer, you could still have a race condition. Trust me, there is absolutely no problems with embedding widgets in Frames. There is definitely a bug in your code. The evidence seems to point to threading since it is a documented fact that Tkinter isn't thread safe.

Comment: @Mayur Patel: consider this possibility: you click on the slider. Still in the main thread, Tk will try to update the appearance of the button before it calls the command. Now, possibly, the other thread is given priority *before you cancel the timer* and it tries to update the UI too. If you *ever* try to update a GUI element from another thread, your code will eventually break.

Comment: First, there seems to be some intent for Tkinter to be thread safe, but I'm willing to believe that it's not.  http://bugs.python.org/issue11077.   Second, by completely disabling the timer thread, the problem still occurs.  Your "consider this possibility" condition doesn't occur; there's only one thread.  Thread problems tend to be intermittent and feel non-deterministic.  This problem is repeatable and immediate.  Of course, parenting widgets in Frames is a common operation; and of course there is a bug in my code.  This is why I am asking for assistance. :-)